# Como parar um Loop Infinito For - Vue

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js, loop, for

Eu estou fazendo um projeto com VueJS e tenho essas duas funções que percorrem um array fornecido por um fetch de um JSON.

```
import { api, getCep } from "@/services.js";
export default {
  name: 'Casos',
  data() {
    return {
      //cep: '',
      //bairro: '',
      bairros: '',
      casoPorBairro: '',
      casos: null,
      valores: '',
      totalCasos: '',
      totalObitos: '',
      changeView: false,
      listBairros: [],
      searchBairro: '',
      searchCasos: '',
      searchObitos: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    buscarCep() {
      const cep = this.cep.replace(/\D/g, "");
      if(cep.length === 8) {
        getCep(cep).then(r => {
          this.bairro = r.data.bairro;
        })
      }
    },
    getCasos() {
      api.get(`/covid19.min.json`).then(r => {
        this.casos = r.data.bairros; // => PRODUCTION
        //this.casos = r.data; // => DEVELOPMENT
      });
    },
    showBairro() {
      for(let i = 0; i < this.casos.length; i++){
        this.listBairros.push(this.casos[i]);
      }
      const result = this.listBairros.find(list => list.bairro === this.bairros);
      if(result) {
        this.searchBairro = result.bairro;
        this.searchCasos = result.casos;
        this.searchObitos = result.obitos
      }
    },
    getValorMax() {
      let sumCasos = 0;
      let sumObitos = 0;
      for(let i = 0; i < this.casos.length; i++){
        this.valores = this.casos[i].casos;
        sumCasos = sumCasos + this.casos[i].casos;
        sumObitos = sumObitos + this.casos[i].obitos;
      }
      this.totalCasos = sumCasos.toLocaleString();
      this.totalObitos = sumObitos.toLocaleString();
    },
    changeColor() {
      const btnList = document.querySelector('button[data-btn="list"]');
      const btnTable = document.querySelector('button[data-btn="table"]');
      if(this.changeView === false) {
        btnList.classList.remove('active');
        btnTable.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        btnList.classList.add('active');
        btnTable.classList.remove('active');
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getCasos();
  },
  beforeUpdate() {
    this.getValorMax();
    this.getCasos();
    this.showBairro();
  },
  updated() {
    this.changeColor();
  }
}
```

Como eu preciso esperar meu fetch ocorrer para inserir os dados do json no array, ambas funções estão sendo chamadas no método `beforeUpdate()` do Vue.
Porém, o for loop de ambas funções estão gerando um loop infinito.

Segue arquivo completo: https://github.com/GuiiHenriq/sp-covid19/blob/master/src/components/Casos.vue

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Esclarece 2 coisas: 1) porque chamas `this.getCasos();` no beforeUpdate e não somente 1 vez quando o componente carrega? 2) a fonte de dados sobre a qual tudo o resto é calculado vem desse `this.getCasos();` certo?

Comment: Sergio, seu comentário me ajudou a esclarecer o problema, realmente o loop infinito esteva sendo causado pois o getCasos() estava sendo chamado no beforeUpdate também, o correto é chamar apenas quando cria o componente.

Comment: Se responderes às minhas perguntas tens um bonus de uma resposta a dizer como podes fazer isso de uma maneira melhor ;)

Comment: 1) Como expliquei foi um erro, atualmente estou chamando o `this.getCasos()` no método `created()`.
2) Isso exato, o `this.getCasos()` é onde eu tenho minha função de get do axios. As duas outras funções `this.showBairro()` e `this.getValorMax()` estão utilizando o `this.getCasos()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sendo que tudo o que esse componente precisa provêm de dados que `this.getCasos()` foi buscar então elas (ou os valores que geram) devem por defenição ser *computed properties*, criando assim um fluxo reativo. Como tens (o `this.getCasos()` a ser chamado em cada beforeUpdate) cria um loop infinito pois quando `this.casos` receber esses novos valores o beforeUpdate é chamado novamente, e por aí em diante, ciclicamente.

A lógica é criar todo o restante conteúdo quando `this.casos` mudar e sem ter de chamar métodos manualmente.

A maneira de fazer isso seria assim:

```js
new Vue({
  name: "Casos",
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      //cep: '',
      //bairro: '',
      bairros: "",
      casoPorBairro: "",
      casos: [],
      changeView: false
    };
  },
  computed: {
    searchBairro() {
      const searchString = this.bairros.trim();
      return (
        searchString &&
        this.casos.find(({
          bairro
        }) => bairro === this.bairros)
      );
    },
    totais() {
      let sumCasos = 0;
      let sumObitos = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.casos.length; i++) {
        sumCasos = sumCasos + this.casos[i].casos;
        sumObitos = sumObitos + this.casos[i].obitos;
      }

      return {
        casos: sumCasos.toLocaleString(),
        obitos: sumObitos.toLocaleString()
      };
    }
  },
  methods: {
    buscarCep() {
      const cep = this.cep.replace(/\D/g, "");
      if (cep.length === 8) {
        getCep(cep).then(r => {
          this.bairro = r.data.bairro;
        });
      }
    },
    getCasos() {
      // exemplo estático:
      const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GuiiHenriq/sp-covid19/master/public/covid19.min.json';

      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(r => {
          this.casos = r.bairros;
        });
    },
    changeColor() {
      const btnList = document.querySelector('button[data-btn="list"]');
      const btnTable = document.querySelector('button[data-btn="table"]');
      if (this.changeView === false) {
        btnList.classList.remove("active");
        btnTable.classList.add("active");
      } else {
        btnList.classList.add("active");
        btnTable.classList.remove("active");
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getCasos();
  },
  updated() {
    this.changeColor();
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.casos,
.infos {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  color: #706fd3
}

.casos-content,
.infos-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.infos-content {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.infos div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 22px 12px;
  width: 215px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dbe9f5;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(31, 70, 88, .04);
}

.infos div h1 {
  margin-right: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 48px;
  letter-spacing: -1.29px;
}

.infos div p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.search {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 30px 0 60px 0;
}

.search section {
  padding: 22px 0 22px 12px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dbe9f5;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(31, 70, 88, .04);
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}

.search section p span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.casos section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.casos i {
  font-size: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #345;
}

.casos button.active i {
  color: #706fd3;
}


/* Table/Cards */

.casos-content li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 22px 0 22px 12px;
  width: 215px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dbe9f5;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(31, 70, 88, .04);
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.casos li:last-child {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.casos li span {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* List */

.casos-content-list {
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.casos-content-list li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.list-head {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(31, 70, 88, .04);
}

.list-head li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.list-infos {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(31, 70, 88, .04);
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.list-infos:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.casos-content-list .list-infos p {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#busca {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
}

#busca:focus,
#busca:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#lupa {
  width: 62px;
  height: 62px;
  background: url("../assets/search.svg") no-repeat center center;
  text-indent: -150px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .infos div,
  .casos li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .casos li:last-child {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<main id="app">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="infos">
      <h2>Dados Gerais</h2>
      <section class="infos-content">
        <div>
          <p>Casos Confirmados</p>
          <h1>{{ totais.casos }}</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Óbitos</p>
          <h1>{{ totais.obitos }}</h1>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>

    <main class="search">
      <h2>Procure seu bairro</h2>
      <form>
        <!--<input id="cep" name="cep" type="text" placeholder="Bela Vista" v-model="cep" @keyup="buscarCep">-->
        <input id="cep" name="cep" type="text" placeholder="Bela Vista" v-model="bairros" />
      </form>

      <section v-if="searchBairro">
        <p><span>Bairro:</span> {{ searchBairro.bairro }}</p>
        <p><span>Casos:</span> {{ searchBairro.casos }}</p>
        <p><span>Óbitos:</span> {{ searchBairro.obitos }}</p>
      </section>
    </main>

    <main class="casos">
      <section>
        <div>
          <h2>Todos os casos</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button @click="changeView = false" data-btn="table" class="active">
              <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
            </button>
          <button @click="changeView = true" data-btn="list">
              <i class="fas fa-list-alt"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
      </section>

      <ul class="casos-content" v-if="changeView === false">
        <li v-for="caso in casos" :key="caso.bairro">
          <p><span>Bairro:</span> {{ caso.bairro }}</p>
          <p><span>Casos:</span> {{ caso.casos }}</p>
          <p><span>Óbitos:</span> {{ caso.obitos }}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="casos-content-list" v-else>
        <div class="list-head">
          <li>
            <p><span>Bairro</span></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p><span>Casos</span></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p><span>Óbitos</span></p>
          </li>
        </div>
        <li v-for="caso in casos" :key="caso.bairro" class="list-infos">
          <p>{{ caso.bairro }}</p>
          <p>{{ caso.casos }}</p>
          <p>{{ caso.obitos }}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </main>
  </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

---

**PS:** [enviei um PR](https://github.com/GuiiHenriq/sp-covid19/pull/1) se quiseres usar esta versão que sugeri aqui.

Comment: Entendi, não lembrava do uso da computed properties, mas com sua explicação pude compreender.
Aceitei seu PR e fiz o merge com a master, fiz os testes local e em produção, funcionou perfeitamente.

Agradeço pela sua explicação foi de grande ajuda e obrigado por contribuir com o projeto também. **Muito obrigado mesmo!**